# PDO much slower than mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using a PDO object in PHP to run MYSQL queries, and I have been trying to work on a query to speed it up. The query is as follows, as seen in my PHP file:

```
$query = 
"SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE f.position, s.item_id, s.item_type, s.title, s.caption, s.date
FROM apiv2.search_all s 
INNER JOIN apiv2.tags t 
USING(item_id, item_type) 
LEFT JOIN apiv2.featured f 
ON t.item_id = f.item_id AND t.item_type = f.item_type AND f.feature_type = :id 
WHERE t.tag = 'FeaturedContent'
ORDER BY position IS NULL, position ASC, date";

$mysql_vars[':id'] = $id;
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($vars);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This query runs significantly differently depending on whether I include the ORDER BY clause, but only at the MYSQL console:

```
 - MYSQL Console with ORDER BY: 1.07 sec
    - starting  0.000141
    - Opening tables    0.001416
    - System lock   0.000003
    - Table lock    0.000007
    - init  0.000021
    - checking permissions  0.000001
    - checking permissions  0.000036
    - optimizing    0.000027
    - statistics    0.000027
    - preparing 0.000015
    - Creating tmp table    0.003440
    - executing 0.000001
    - Copying to tmp table  1.050029
    - Sorting result    0.013097
    - Sending data  0.000295
    - end   0.000002
    - removing tmp table    0.002045
    - end   0.000003
    - query end 0.000002
    - freeing items 0.000331
    - logging slow query    0.000002
    - cleaning up   0.000007
 - MYSQL Console unordered output: .0053 sec
    - starting  0.000076
    - Opening tables    0.001506
    - System lock   0.000002
    - Table lock    0.000005
    - init  0.000015
    - checking permissions  0.000001
    - checking permissions  0.000022
    - optimizing    0.000012
    - statistics    0.000021
    - preparing 0.000011
    - executing 0.000001
    - Sending data  0.002895
    - end   0.000002
    - query end 0.000001
    - freeing items 0.000078
    - logging slow query    0.000000
    - cleaning up   0.000002
 - PDO Prepared stmt ORDER BY: 1.18 sec
    - 'Status' => 'starting', 'Duration' => '0.000147'
    - 'Status' => 'Opening tables', 'Duration' => '0.000784'
    - 'Status' => 'System lock', 'Duration' => '0.000004'
    - 'Status' => 'Table lock', 'Duration' => '0.000007'
    - 'Status' => 'init', 'Duration' => '0.000017'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000002'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000028'
    - 'Status' => 'optimizing', 'Duration' => '0.000018'
    - 'Status' => 'statistics', 'Duration' => '0.000026'
    - 'Status' => 'preparing', 'Duration' => '0.000014'
    - 'Status' => 'Creating tmp table', 'Duration' => '0.002112'
    - 'Status' => 'executing', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'Copying to tmp table', 'Duration' => '1.033056'
    - 'Status' => 'Sorting result', 'Duration' => '0.013759'
    - 'Status' => 'Sending data', 'Duration' => '0.073144'
    - 'Status' => 'end', 'Duration' => '0.000003'
    - 'Status' => 'removing tmp table', 'Duration' => '0.001999'
    - 'Status' => 'end', 'Duration' => '0.000004'
    - 'Status' => 'query end', 'Duration' => '0.000007'
    - 'Status' => 'freeing items', 'Duration' => '0.000118'
    - 'Status' => 'logging slow query', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'cleaning up', 'Duration' => '0.000003'
 - PDO Prepared stmt unordered output: 1.06 sec
    - 'Status' => 'starting', 'Duration' => '0.000074'
    - 'Status' => 'Opening tables', 'Duration' => '0.001364'
    - 'Status' => 'System lock', 'Duration' => '0.000004'
    - 'Status' => 'Table lock', 'Duration' => '0.000007'
    - 'Status' => 'init', 'Duration' => '0.000017'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000026'
    - 'Status' => 'optimizing', 'Duration' => '0.000015'
    - 'Status' => 'statistics', 'Duration' => '0.000027'
    - 'Status' => 'preparing', 'Duration' => '0.000013'
    - 'Status' => 'executing', 'Duration' => '0.000002'
    - 'Status' => 'Sending data', 'Duration' => '1.048216'
    - 'Status' => 'end', 'Duration' => '0.000003'
    - 'Status' => 'query end', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'freeing items', 'Duration' => '0.000122'
    - 'Status' => 'logging slow query', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'cleaning up', 'Duration' => '0.000003' 
 - MYSQL functions from PHP unordered: 1.09 sec
    - 'Status' => 'starting', 'Duration' => '0.000109'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000002'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000004'
    - 'Status' => 'Opening tables', 'Duration' => '0.002101'
    - 'Status' => 'System lock', 'Duration' => '0.000004'
    - 'Status' => 'Table lock', 'Duration' => '0.000009'
    - 'Status' => 'init', 'Duration' => '0.000032'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000003'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000057'
    - 'Status' => 'optimizing', 'Duration' => '0.000033'
    - 'Status' => 'statistics', 'Duration' => '0.000065'
    - 'Status' => 'preparing', 'Duration' => '0.000032'
    - 'Status' => 'executing', 'Duration' => '0.000005'
    - 'Status' => 'Sending data', 'Duration' => '1.000079'
    - 'Status' => 'end', 'Duration' => '0.000005'
    - 'Status' => 'query end', 'Duration' => '0.000002'
    - 'Status' => 'freeing items', 'Duration' => '0.000300'
    - 'Status' => 'logging slow query', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'cleaning up', 'Duration' => '0.000007'
 - MYSQL functions from PHP w/ ORDER BY: 1.09 sec
    - 'Status' => 'starting', 'Duration' => '0.000148'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'Opening tables', 'Duration' => '0.000559'
    - 'Status' => 'System lock', 'Duration' => '0.000002'
    - 'Status' => 'Table lock', 'Duration' => '0.000006'
    - 'Status' => 'init', 'Duration' => '0.000019'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'checking permissions', 'Duration' => '0.000030'
    - 'Status' => 'optimizing', 'Duration' => '0.000018'
    - 'Status' => 'statistics', 'Duration' => '0.000025'
    - 'Status' => 'preparing', 'Duration' => '0.000015'
    - 'Status' => 'Creating tmp table', 'Duration' => '0.001828'
    - 'Status' => 'executing', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'Copying to tmp table', 'Duration' => '0.958071'
    - 'Status' => 'Sorting result', 'Duration' => '0.013502'
    - 'Status' => 'Sending data', 'Duration' => '0.088148'
    - 'Status' => 'end', 'Duration' => '0.000003'
    - 'Status' => 'removing tmp table', 'Duration' => '0.002037'
    - 'Status' => 'end', 'Duration' => '0.000003'
    - 'Status' => 'query end', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'freeing items', 'Duration' => '0.000112'
    - 'Status' => 'logging slow query', 'Duration' => '0.000001'
    - 'Status' => 'cleaning up', 'Duration' => '0.000004'
```

EXPLAINS:

WITH ORDERING

```
|-id-|-select_type-|-table----|-type---|-possible_keys--------|-key-----------------|-key_len-|-ref-------------------------------------|-rows--|-Extra
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-s--------|-ALL----|-PRIMARY,search_index-|-NULL----------------|-NULL----|-NULL------------------------------------|-92166-|-Using temporary; Using filesort
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-tags-----|-eq_ref-|-PRIMARY--------------|-PRIMARY-------------|-426-----|-apiv2.s.item_id,apiv2.s.item_type,const-|-1-----|-Using where; Using index
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-featured-|-ref----|-type_position_index--|-type_position_index-|-62------|-const-----------------------------------|-3-----|-Using index
```

WITHOUT ORDERING

```
|-id-|-select_type-|-table----|-type---|-possible_keys--------|-key-----------------|-key_len-|-ref-------------------------------------|-rows--|-Extra
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-s--------|-ALL----|-PRIMARY,search_index-|-NULL----------------|-NULL----|-NULL------------------------------------|-88346-|-
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-tags-----|-eq_ref-|-PRIMARY--------------|-PRIMARY-------------|-426-----|-apiv2.s.item_id,apiv2.s.item_type,const-|-1-----|-Using where; Using index
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-featured-|-ref----|-type_position_index--|-type_position_index-|-62------|-const-----------------------------------|-3-----|-Using index
```

**TABLE: search_all**

```
CREATE TABLE `search_all` (  
  `item_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `item_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `caption` text,  
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`item_type`),  
  UNIQUE KEY `search_index` (`item_id`,`item_type`,`date`),  
  KEY `date_index` (`date`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  


|-id-|-select_type-|-table------|-type-|-possible_keys-|-key--|-key_len-|-ref--|-rows--|-Extra
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-search_all-|-ALL--|-NULL----------|-NULL-|-NULL----|-NULL-|-74785-|-
```

**TABLE: tags**

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (  
  `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  `item_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `item_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`item_type`,`tag`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  


|-id-|-select_type-|-table-|-type--|-possible_keys-|-key-----|-key_len-|-ref--|-rows---|-Extra
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-tags--|-index-|-NULL----------|-PRIMARY-|-426-----|-NULL-|-197400-|-Using index
```

**TABLE: featured**

```
CREATE TABLE `featured` (  
  `position` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `item_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `item_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `feature_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  PRIMARY KEY (`position`,`item_type`,`item_id`,`feature_type`),  
  KEY `type_position_index` (`feature_type`,`position`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  


|-id-|-select_type-|-table----|-type--|-possible_keys-|-key-----------------|-key_len-|-ref--|-rows-|-Extra
|-1--|-SIMPLE------|-featured-|-index-|-NULL----------|-type_position_index-|-66------|-NULL-|-13---|-Using index
```

Why is there no difference between the unordering in the PDO or MSQL from PHP? Is there any way I could make it faster?

Comment: Post the tables definitions (including the indexes) and the (EXPLAIN) execution plan of the query.

Comment: Can you really reproduce this? "Sending Data" seems to consume too much time in the last example. Maybe its just a "lag", or a caching issue.

Comment: I believe the time is checked at the beginning of each step in the profile, meaning the long ones are actually a bad review of the previous step, which would point all the fingers at the 'executing' step

Comment: Seems like running with no cache defeats one of the primary benefits of PDO; namely, that it caches your prepared statement so that future calls to the same query can avoid the cost of preparing the query. I assume the slower execution time is due to PDO "sanitizing" the parameters, something which neither the myslq_* nor the mysqli_* query functions do.

Comment: The no-cache is just there for testing purposes, to make sure that the times are correct (uncached). We will be using apc for caching, as well as mysql, but at roll-out. Would the 'sanitation' step be felt during execution, and not preparation? And why would the runtime be the same with or without ordering?

Comment: @Ripptor: And as I feared you have too lengthy fields! `tag varchar(100)` ? What kind of tags do you put in there?

Comment: The primary key of `search_all` has length 40 and of `tags` has length **140** !!

Comment: InnoDB can be quite efficient when the primary (and foreign) keys are as short as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your order by is for an indexed column and the optimizer thinks its a good idea to use the index an "ORDER BY" will result in a sort which takes significant time and resources for any result set of any size.

The reason the PDO version is taking longer is that your script is consuming rows slower than SQLServer can serve them up, so the Database is waiting for your program. As you are using an interpreted language and an API which does a considerable amount of manipulation of the row result this is only to be expected. This delay "sending data" is much larger (0.75 sec and 1.04 sec) than the overhead from the sort.

Note the slow retrieval is compounded by the order by. In the case of the unordered SQL the rows will be sent as soon as they are selected. In the case of the ordered select all the rows will have been selected and then sorted before the first result row is sent.

Comment: I have an index on the position, but since most rows aren't joined to featured, most won't have a position. I had implemented a PHP sort to skip the sorting on the MYSQL side, but since removing the sort didn't speed it up I have no improvement.. If I could speed up the unordered PDO, then I think it could work. Do you have nay suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please post the tables definitions (fields, types of fields, etc)?**

I would first add a simple index on `date` in table `search_all` and

a simple index on `tag` in table `tags`.

Comment: Table definitions added. There is a date index in search_all, and the tags table is a triple-key (item_id, item_type, tag)

Comment: @Ripptor: An index `(tag)` is very different than index `(item_id, item_type, tag)`